# Css Semantic UI responsive table won't collapse properly in Safari

Tags: css, mobile, html-table, semantic-ui

I am currently using Semantic UI's tables, which are supposed to be mobile-responsive (example and description here http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html)

My only problem is having apparently the same settings, Safari and Chrome will present mobile version of tables, on my website, in strangest ways, but definitely not blocks as in normally in their website.

I have added normalize.css but it seems to not work for this issue.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was not one with Semantic UI, but one with Webkit.

> Webkit overrides display: block; and computes it to be `display: table-cell;` in a td when there is no `<!DOCTYPE html>` declared for your html.

Source:
[Display:Block not working in Chrome or Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556310/displayblock-not-working-in-chrome-or-safari)

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem. I had two rows originally in every other browser but Safari.  In Safari, it was just one row.  This fixed it for me: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/849

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering little tomato. In fact your answer did not help me directly as it did not solve my issue. But doing so made me look again at the problem differently, which led to success. For this, thank you!

Comment: @BenedictGagnon I'm glad you were able to fix it! :)