# Responsive table works ONLY in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, media

I used the jQuery from: http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Creating-Responsive-Mobile-friendly-Tables-with-jQuery-Table-Mobilize.html to make an already existing table responsive.  It's working wonderfully in Firefox, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's not working in Chrome, Opera, or IE.

I thought media queries at first, but they're working on all browsers.  However, the responsiveness stops short in any browser besides Firefox.  So maybe the jQuery?

This is my first time messing with a responsive table... so don't be bashful about pointing out anything blatantly obvious :) I probably am not seeing it.

I, unfortunately, did not create the original table, so I going off of what's already in place.  I'm wondering if the the fancybox is messing with it somehow... I know it's not set up responsive as of yet.

Any suggestions?  Using the red and blue background color for ease of seeing the media queries.

Table is on http://www.infraredcamerasinc.com/efficient/pages/lenscalculator/index.html

CSS:

```
    table.tableMobilize tbody,table.tableMobilize td,table.tableMobilize th,table.tableMobilize tr{border:0;padding:0;white-space:normal;font-size:1em}

    table.tableMobilize td,table.tableMobilize th{padding:8px;/*line-height:1.42857143;*/vertical-align:top;/*border-top:1px solid #ddd;*/text-align:left}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized{display:block}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized tfooter,table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized thead{display:none;visibility:hidden}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized td:hide{display:none!important}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized tbody,table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized td,table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized th,table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized tr{display:block}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized td[data-title]:before{content:attr(data-title) ": ";color:#555}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized th[data-title]:first-child:before{content:''}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized th:first-child{font-size:1.4em;border-top:none;vertical-align:bottom;margin-top:.5em;text-transform:uppercase;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;font-weight:400;text-align:left;color:#111}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized td:first-child{border-top:2px solid #aaa}

    table.tableMobilize.tableMobilized tr:first-child td:first-child{border-top:none!important}

    table.tableMobilized.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) td{background-color:green}



@media screen and (max-width:767px) {

    table.tableMobilize{display:block}

    table.tableMobilize tfooter,table.tableMobilize thead{display:none;visibility:hidden}

    table.tableMobilize td:hide{display:none!important}

    table.tableMobilize tbody,table.tableMobilize td,table.tableMobilize th,table.tableMobilize tr{display:block}

    table.tableMobilize td[data-title]:before{content:attr(data-title) ": ";color:#555}

    table.tableMobilize th[data-title]:first-child:before{content:''}

    table.tableMobilize th:first-child{font-size:1.4em;border-top:none;vertical-align:bottom;margin-top:.5em;text-transform:uppercase;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;font-weight:400;text-align:left;color:#111}

    table.tableMobilize td:first-child{/*border-top:2px solid #aaa*/}

    table.tableMobilize tr:first-child td:first-child{/*border-top:none!important*/}

    table.tableMobilize.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) td{background-color:red}

    }



@media screen and (min-width:768px) {

    table.tableMobilize>thead th{vertical-align:bottom;border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;border-top:0;padding:8px;line-height:1.42857143}

    table.tableMobilize.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd){background-color:blue}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it isn't your CSS, it is actually your HTML DOCTYPE that is causing the issue. It appears the 4.01 Transitional DOCTYPE overrides the "display: block" on TD elements and sets them to "table-cell".

This change should resolve your problem, it worked when I tested it:

Change:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Here is another thread that had the same issue:
[Display:Block not working in Chrome or Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556310/displayblock-not-working-in-chrome-or-safari)

Comment: You are a Godsend!!! Thanks so much, works perfectly!  Didn't even think about changing around the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Hey no problem! It was an odd one, glad I could help!